# How to write alphanumeric pattern in HTML5?

Tags: html, regex

I have a job title field in a form, where I want it to allow a response which contains only letters and numbers, where at least one letter is required and any numbers are optional. I am using the following pattern in my input tag:

```
pattern="\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*"
```

This pattern checks out on the RegEx testers I have tried to use, yet when I provide an answer on my form of "Manager 2" it will not let me continue. Is there something different about how browsers interpret

Comment: Show us an example input where it fails...

Comment: What does it fail with? If you plan to also support whitespaces, try `pattern="[0-9\s]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*"`.

Comment: `Manager 2` contains a space and then `2` but your pattern requires at least 2 chars. Try `\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*(?: \w+)*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [pattern attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) on a form, the `^` and `$` are implied so it will match the whole value. Your pattern `\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*` matches at least a single char a-z but not a space.

If you want to match `Manager 2` you could use your pattern followed by a group which repeats 0+ times matching a space and 1+ word characters.

```
\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*(?: \w+)*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4iaeXi/1)

Note that `\w` also matches an underscore.

A bit broader pattern to allow multiple spaces, and also at the end:

```
^\w*[a-zA-Z][ \w]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5jSS3I/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your original expression is just fine and missing space. Here, we can start with a simple pattern, maybe something similar to:

```
[A-Za-z\s0-9]+
```

If it was necessary, we could add capturing group around it to save our data in `$1`:

```
([A-Za-z\s0-9]+)
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zDFoz8/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /([A-Za-z\s0-9]+)/gm;
const str = `Manager 2`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

### [DOMO](https://regex101.com/r/zDFoz8/1)